# Simple Javascript Calling function not working/don't know how to get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I'm trying to call a function and not the alert and I thought it was as easy as just doing something like this: FunctionsName(); and delete the alert(''); but it's not working for me :(

Can someone please look at the code I have below and tell me what is wrong ?

Thank you so much!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var comper;
function checkComper() {
    var onResponse = function(comperNow) {  

        if (comper === undefined) {
            comper = comperNow;
            return;
        }

        if (comper !== comperNow) {
            // show a message to the visitor
            alert("New Info Added"); // <--*** I WANT TO TAKE THIS OUT AND CALL $("#append").click(function(e)

            comper = comperNow;
        }
    };
    $.get('getlastupdate.php', onResponse);
}

var tid = setInterval(checkComper, 2000); 

$(function() {

    var $table = $("table.tablesorter");
    $("#append").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get('updatetable.php', function(data) 
              {
                  $table
                  .find('tbody')
                  .html('')
                  .append(data);
                  $table.trigger("update", [true]);
              });
    });
/*........ and so on.... */
</script>
```

Comment: Attaching an event handler inside an interval doesn't really sound like a good idea.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to switch the two functions? Looks like you are trying to use JQuery also, is it loaded?

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon solved my problem but how do I do what I want to do without attaching an event handler inside an interval ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changin that :

```
alert("New Info Added");
```

to that :

```
$('#append').trigger('click');
```

It will simulate a click and trigger the function.

Comment: Sweet! That works! Thank you now, but I'm worried what @adeneo what talking about ?

Comment: @msvuze He probably missunderstood your question and though you wanted to bind the event instead of calling it.

Comment: ahh, got it. Thank you again I so happy you helped me with this question. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

One thing important to distinguish:

`alert("New Info Added")` is a function.  Actually, `alert()` is a function, being passed the parameter "New Info Added".

`$('#append').click(function(e) {` is **not** a function, at least, not in the same way.  `$('#append')` is a jQuery selector function, which selects all elements with an id of "append".  `$('#append').click()` is a function that sets a click event on all elements returned in the selector.

What the whole syntax of `$('#append').click(function(e) {` means is on its own a syntax error.  What you're doing is telling the elements found in the selector what their click function should be.  But the `function(e) {` says that it's the start of the code of the function.  That line of code isn't complete until the ending `})` - the `}` closing the function declaration and the `)` closing the call to `click`.

So, you can't simply replace `alert("New Info Added")`, which is a complete function call, with `$('#append').click(function(e) {`, because it's a syntax error - you haven't completed the `function(e)` declaration, nor the `click` function call.  You can trigger the click function, as Karl's answer told you.  Or, you can use the shortcut:

```
$('#append').click()
```

Note that this *is* a full proper sentence, and can therefore replace the `alert`.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott for your easy to understand explanation! :) Thanks!